# Всем привет, я не знаю как при клонировании input type color через template, делать градиент с помощью клонированных input-ов

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let btnGradient = document.querySelector('.btnGradient');

btnGradient.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  let colorGradientFirst = document.querySelector('.color1');
  let colorGradientSecond = document.querySelector('.color2');
  let Gradient = 'linear-gradient(' + colorGradientFirst.value + ',' + colorGradientSecond.value + ')';
  console.log(Gradient);
  ball.style.backgroundImage = Gradient;
});

let btnAddColorGR = document.querySelector('.addColorGR');
let template = document.querySelector('#template').content;
let newItemTemplate = template.querySelector('.input');
let i = 2;

btnAddColorGR.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  i += 1;
  evt.preventDefault();
  let form = document.querySelector('form');
  let task = newItemTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  task.classList.add('colorGR');
  task.classList.add('color' + i);
  form.append(task);

});
```

```css
.ball {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: none 1s ease-out;
  transition-property: left, top, background-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(115, 240, 19), rgb(138, 222, 22), rgb(161, 204, 24), rgb(184, 187, 27), rgb(207, 169, 29), rgb(230, 151, 32), rgb(230, 129, 30), rgb(231, 107, 27), rgb(231, 85, 25), rgb(231, 62, 23), rgb(232, 40, 20), rgb(232, 18, 18));
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="ball" id="ball"></div>

<form action="" class="form">
  <input class="colorGR color1" type="color">
  <input class="colorGR color2" type="color">
  
  <template id="template">
    <input type="color" class="input">
  </template>

</form>

<button class="addColorGR" value="">
  <img src="icons8-ios-50.png" alt="icons8-ios-50">
</button>
<button class="button btnGradient">ColorGradient</button>
```

Comment: А для чего здесь template, если он нигде не используется, и инпуты и так отображаются? Ну нужно циклом пройтись... `console.log( [...document.querySelectorAll('.colorGR')].map( e => e.value ).join(", ") );`

Comment: Извините за не точный вопрос. Я имел ввиду когда мы добавляем новый input type color у мяча был градиентный фон с теми input-ами которые есть на странице. А не только которые были заданы изначально @OPTIMUSPRIME

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду привыкать. @OPTIMUSPRIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было использовать простейший цикл и пробежаться по всем элементам.

>> https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for

Хотя вместо классического цикла, бывает удобно использовать встроенные методы массивов...

`let col = [...document.querySelectorAll('.colorGR')].map( input => input.value ).join(', ');`

Стрелочные функции сначала пугают, к ним надо привыкнуть.

```js
let btnGradient = document.querySelector('.btnGradient');

btnGradient.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.colorGR');
  let colors = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
    colors.push( inputs[i].value );
  }
  console.log('colors → ' + JSON.stringify(colors) );
  
  let Gradient = 'linear-gradient(' + colors.join(', ') + ')';
  console.log(Gradient);
  ball.style.backgroundImage = Gradient;
});

let btnAddColorGR = document.querySelector('.addColorGR');
let template = document.querySelector('#template').content;
let newItemTemplate = template.querySelector('.input');
let i = 2;

btnAddColorGR.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  i += 1;
  evt.preventDefault();
  let form = document.querySelector('form');
  let task = newItemTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  task.classList.add('colorGR');
  task.classList.add('color' + i);
  form.append(task);

});
```

```css
.ball {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: none 1s ease-out;
  transition-property: left, top, background-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(115, 240, 19), rgb(138, 222, 22), rgb(161, 204, 24), rgb(184, 187, 27), rgb(207, 169, 29), rgb(230, 151, 32), rgb(230, 129, 30), rgb(231, 107, 27), rgb(231, 85, 25), rgb(231, 62, 23), rgb(232, 40, 20), rgb(232, 18, 18));
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="ball" id="ball"></div>

<form action="" class="form">
  <input class="colorGR color1" type="color">
  <input class="colorGR color2" type="color">

  <template id="template">
    <input type="color" class="input">
  </template>

</form>

<button class="addColorGR" value="">
  <img src="icons8-ios-50.png" alt="icons8-ios-50">
</button>
<button class="button btnGradient">ColorGradient</button>
```